# Django Queryset filter get all elements

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My code looks like below

Extracting the tag-id from the Car class

tags  = [UUID('1b2990eb-f625-4458-8878-1ab199e3e72b'), UUID('6e663259-9bf0-4e2d-8bf6-11be14218036')]

When I try the below codes :

```
Car.objects.filter(uuid__in=tags).values_list('id',flat=True)[0] -> Output 11

Car.objects.filter(uuid__in=tags).values_list('id',flat=True).all()[0] -> Output :11
           
Car.objects.filter(uuid__in=tags).values_list('id',flat=True).all() -> Output : <QuerySet [11,12]>
```

I want the output in the format of [11,12]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QuerySet` is iterable, and when you iterate over it, you get the items (model objects, tuples, dictionaries or scalar values). Therefore we can use [**`list(…)`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) to collect the elements:

```
list(Car.objects.filter(uuid__in=tags).values_list('id',flat=True))
```